# merge, merge sort

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка, информатика

Я пытаюсь написать сортировку слиянием, но программа падает. Поэтому решила для начала проверить правильно ли работает функция merge, но она работает нормально.

```
vector<int> merge(vector<int>& b, vector<int>& c){
size_t nb = b.size();
size_t nc = c.size();
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
vector<int> d;

while(i <= nb && j <= nc){
    if (b[i] <= c[j]){
        d.push_back(b[i]);
        i++;
    } else {
        d.push_back(c[j]);
        j++;
    }
}

while (i < nb){
    d.push_back(b[i]);
    i++;
}

while (j < nc){
    d.push_back(c[j]);
    j++;
}

return d;}
```

Вот сама функция merge_sort:

```
vector<int> merge_sort(vector<int>& a, int left, int right){
vector<int> res;
if (left < right){
    int m = right / 2;
    vector<int> b, c;
    b = merge_sort(a, left, m - 1);
    c = merge_sort(a, m, right);
    res = merge(b, c);
}
return res;}
```

С чем может быть связана проблема? Я подозреваю, что проблема где-то в условии

> if (left < right)

В main вызываю merge_sort(a, 0, n), где n размер массива a.

Comment: Нужно середину правильно обозначить `[a .. [(a+b)/2] [(a+b)/2]+1 .. b ]`

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> merge_sort(vector<int>& a, int left, int right){
vector<int> res;
if (left < right){
    //int m = right / 2;
    int m = (left + right) / 2;
    vector<int> b, c;
    //b = merge_sort(a, 0, m - 1);
    b = merge_sort(a, left, m );
    //c = merge_sort(a, m, right);
    c = merge_sort(a, m + 1, right);
    res = merge(b, c);
}
else res .push_back( a[left] );
return res;}
```

Comment: Теперь не падает, но ответ все равно не выводит. res остается пустым вектором

Comment: Тогда добавить один оставшийся элемент остался. При `left == right`.